# Pushing numbers into a matrix array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I did:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = Array.new(matrix[0].length, [])
result[0] << 2
result # [[2], [2], [2]]
```

I don't understand why `2` appears in all my subarrays. How can I just push into the first subarray?

```
def transpose(matrix)
  debugger
  result = Array.new(matrix[0].length, []) #HARD - PASS BY REFERENCE ISSUE
  matrix.each do |row|
    row.each_with_index do |el, col_idx|
      result[col_idx] << el
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: I advise reading up on the concept of mutability in Ruby; this is a classic example.

Comment: This is *explicitly* explained using (more or less) your exact example in the documentation of `Array::new` and has also been asked answered dozens of times on [so] already. And no, it doesn't have anything to do with pass-by-reference; Ruby is always strictly pass-by-value (although the values being passed are references, but that is something completely different).

Answer (score 2):

As the doc says:

> An array can also be created by explicitly calling ::new with zero,
>   one (the initial size of the Array) or two arguments (the initial size
>   and a default object).
>
> **Note that the second argument populates the array with references to the same object**

So, whenever you push 2 to the first array, as it's the same object, it does it for the three empty arrays.

If you want to push just to the first array within the "main" array, you could use a block and there assign the default object:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
result = Array.new(matrix[0].length) { [] }
result[0] << 2
p result # [[2], [], []]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
result = Array.new(matrix[0].length, [])
```

You basically created an array with 3 spots, but all 3 spots reference to same array object `[]`. That's why, once you do `result[0] << 2`, the change is reflected in all 3 spots.

```
p result.map &:object_id
#=>  [70264755245320, 70264755245320, 70264755245320] # shows the same reference
```

Change that to use the [block notation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) to create array.:

```
result = Array.new(matrix[0].length) { [] }
```

It constitutes the array by calling the block for **each** element in array, therefore creating the new reference for each position.

For ex:

```
result = Array.new(matrix[0].length) { puts 'here'; [] }
here
here
here
 => [[], [], []]
 result.map &:object_id
# => [70264754918500, 70264754918440, 70264754918340]
```